# Vague "Syntax error in join operation" - Access 2003

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, syntax-error

For some time, I've had this block of SQL which has worked for a month:

```
SELECT 
    F.[BRANCH] AS REGION
    , F.[ACCOUNT]
    , F.[EFFECTIVE]
    , F.[POLICY]
    , F.[DESC2]
    , F.[DESC4]
    , F.[GROSS]
    , F.[COMM]
    , F.[GST ON COMM]
    , F.[ENTRYDATE]
    , I.[TYPE] 
FROM (
    (SELECT [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import].* 
     FROM [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import]  
     WHERE [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import].[EFFECTIVE] <= DateValue("30/05/2012")  
        AND [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import].[GROSS] >= 0  
        AND [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import].[DESC4] IN ('RNWL', 'NEWB', 'EP')  
        AND [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import].[DUEYR] = 2012) AS F 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT IPM_ACCTXREF.* FROM IPM_ACCTXREF  
                        WHERE IPM_ACCTXREF.TYPE 
                            IN (SELECT [Evolve - Account Types].[Account Types] 
                                FROM [Evolve - Account Types])
                        ) AS I ON F.[ACCOUNT] = I.[ACCOUNT]
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT  [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import].* 
                  FROM [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import]  
                  WHERE [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import].[DESC4] IN ('CS', 'CANC', 'JL')
                  ) AS S ON F.[POLICY] = S.[POLICY] 
WHERE S.[POLICY] IS NULL
```

I then wanted to make a change to the DateValue parameter (which would be as simple as changing say, the 5 to a 6).

Problem then is that I get a "Syntax error in JOIN operation" repeated three times. Clicking through each of them, the query then displays the resulting table but with "#Name?" populated in each field.

Not sure what's happening here...

Comment: have you tried reformatting the date from `DD/MM/YYYY` to `MM/DD/YYYY`?  I dont think the format is correct for Access.  if your getting `#Name?` then one of the fields you are referencing is not available.  Try cutting down your nested queries into Views, since your not defining specific fields from the sub-queries.  Your query has way too many possible points of error, that to try and solve it would be a "balding experience".  Break the query apart and try utilizing Views to help with readability.

Comment: The oddity here is that the query has worked on a daily basis for quite some time now. But now, I've noticed that when I make even the smallest of changes (literally can be as small as deleting an unnecessary carriage return or whitespace char) will throw the "Syntax error in JOIN operation" error.

I originally built this query up using views to help my own readability and then combined it into the single query seen above, so I could go back there I suppose, though it would be somewhat unwieldy?

Comment: I did try and change the date formatting though just in case - to no avail. Like any other change I make, Access seems to dislike it :(

Comment: Have you tried doing this same query in the Visual Designer?  Accesses structure for SQL is not my good side but it structures the query in the way that Access understands and processes.  Redevelop the statement in Query Design and so if it produces the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking the query down into subqueries (getting past all that nasty nested `SELECT`statements) fixed the issue. Don't know what the cause was in the first place (it did use to work) though.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rewrite the query being explicit about the fields you need rather than just using `*`.

```
SELECT F.REGION,
       F.ACCOUNT,
       F.EFFECTIVE,
       F.POLICY,
       F.DESC2,
       F.DESC4,
       F.GROSS,
       F.COMM,
       F.[GST ON COMM],
       F.ENTRYDATE,
       I.[TYPE]
FROM   ( (SELECT BRANCH AS REGION,
               ACCOUNT,
               EFFECTIVE,
               POLICY,
               DESC2,
               DESC4,
               GROSS,
               COMM,
               [GST ON COMM],
               ENTRYDATE
        FROM   [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import]
        WHERE  EFFECTIVE<=Datevalue("30/05/2012")
               AND GROSS>=0
               AND DESC4 IN ('RNWL', 'NEWB', 'EP')
               AND DUEYR=2012) AS F
         INNER JOIN (SELECT [TYPE],
                            ACCOUNT
                     FROM   IPM_ACCTXREF
                     WHERE  [TYPE] IN (SELECT [Account Types]
                                       FROM   [Evolve - Account Types])) AS I
           ON F.ACCOUNT=I.ACCOUNT )
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT POLICY
                  FROM   [POLP - Detailed Debtors Import]
                  WHERE  DESC4 IN ('CS', 'CANC', 'JL')) AS S
         ON F.POLICY=S.POLICY
WHERE  S.POLICY IS NULL
```

I'm a bit lost on the purpose of the `LEFT JOIN` here since none of the data from `S` is actually used in the main `SELECT` statement.

You are also using the name `TYPE` as a field name and that's a reserved word.

Comment: I would aggree here with @RenaudBompuis, that usage of the keyword is not suggested at all in Access.  In MS-SQL you can get away with it, due to the way the system indexes fields, but in Access it is a literal meaning and is stored like a flat file system (BTrieve, et al).

Comment: Thanks all, I haven't figured out what caused the issue, but I've managed to get around it by creating several views and querying them. It's less elegant, but it works :)